# Running tests on angulardart 5

Tags: testing, dart, angular-dart

Im trying angulardart 5 (alpha).

To have a "good enough" base, I started of by cloning the example from [`angular_examples`](https://github.com/angular-examples/toh-6/tree/5-dev)

The problem is that README and docs are currently not updated with the new command to use.

Considering `pub serve` became `pub run build_runner serve`, I expected the test command to be `pub run build_runner test`.
But when I use this on [`angular_examples`](https://github.com/angular-examples/toh-6/tree/5-dev) I either get a "No tests ran". Or a crash saying :

> Unable to spawn isolate: The built-in library 'dart:html' is not available on the stand-alone VM.

Same goes for `pub run angular_test --verbose`. Which gives the same crash on dart:html.

---

So, what is the correct command you need to use to run tests on angulardart 5 ?

Answer (score 4):

To run tests use:

```
pub run build_runner test -- -p chrome
```

Here is an example of running tests for [toh-0](https://github.com/angular-examples/toh-0/tree/5-dev):

```
toh-0 > pub run build_runner test -- -p chrome
[INFO] Entrypoint: Generating build script completed, took 220ms
[INFO] BuildDefinition: Reading cached asset graph completed, took 264ms
[INFO] BuildDefinition: Checking for updates since last build completed, took 377ms
[INFO] Build: Running build completed, took 112ms
[INFO] Build: Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 114ms
[INFO] CreateOutputDir: Creating merged output dir `/var/folders/cl/hfrjvtvx6bl6t3m8tc1v9xf40000gq/T/build_runner_testoMQzB9/` completed, took 1.8s
[INFO] CreateOutputDir: Writing asset manifest completed, took 2ms
[INFO] Build: Succeeded after 2.0s with 0 outputs
Running tests...

00:01 +3: All tests passed!
```

Tests for the **other tutorial parts cannot currently be run**.
You can use https://github.com/dart-lang/site-webdev/issues/1277 to track the progress for those tests.

Comment: `other tutorial parts cannot currently be run` that explains everything !